# Eclipse CDT Plugin: Prepend tool to Commandline

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-cdt

currently I am working on a plugin for Eclipse CDT.

What I want to achieve:

Prepend a tool (let us call it cov) before the commandline.

gcc -omain.o main.c

should become
cov gcc -omain.o main.c

I tried to write a custom BuildRunner, which extend ExternalBuildrunner, modifies the tools before invoking the external runner. I do this by editing the COmmandLinePattern

So far it works, if I do not restore the old CommandLinePattern.

Is there a way to update configuration to use the modified tools, and later after invocation write the old configurations back.

Before modifiyng, I backup the tool-commandlinepatterns, so that would not be the problem. I am missing the update step here I guess.

```
public class CovBuildRunner extends ExternalBuildRunner {

private final Set<String> VALUES;

public CovBuildRunner() {
    VALUES = new HashSet<String>();
    VALUES.add("gcc");
    VALUES.add("g++");
}

@Override
public boolean invokeBuild(int kind, IProject project,
        IConfiguration configuration, IBuilder builder, IConsole console,
        IMarkerGenerator markerGenerator,
        IncrementalProjectBuilder projectBuilder, IProgressMonitor monitor)
        throws CoreException {
    Map<ITool, String> cmdPatternBackup = new HashMap<>();
    for (ITool tool : configuration.getTools()) {
        if (cmdPatternBackup.containsKey(tool)) {
            System.out.println("ERROR! TOOL ALREADY MODIFIED!");
        } else if (this.supports(tool)) {
            cmdPatternBackup.put(tool, tool.getCommandLinePattern());
            tool.setCommandLinePattern("cov " + tool.getCommandLinePattern());
            System.out.println(
                    configuration.getToolCommand(tool));
        }
    }
    configuration.getToolChain().set;
    boolean success = invokeExternalBuild(kind, project, configuration, builder, console, markerGenerator, projectBuilder, monitor);
    for (ITool tool : cmdPatternBackup.keySet()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Setting back " + tool.getName() + "\n" + tool.getCommandLinePattern());
        tool.setCommandLinePattern(cmdPatternBackup.get(tool));
    }
    return success;
}

private boolean supports(ITool tool) {
    String command = tool.getToolCommand();
    return VALUES.contains(command);
}

}
```